# Calling GDALGetRasterHistogram( ) from R

Tags: gdal, r, bash, c

I need to calculate a histogram (pixel-count by each unique value, actually) for more than 256 values , the default number of buckets in gdalinfo.
I understand that [GDALGetRasterHistogram](https://gdal.org/doxygen/classGDALRasterBand.html#aa21dcb3609bff012e8f217ebb7c81953) can deal with this, but I can't find an option to call/use that function/tool from R o command-line.

Any idea?

Here is an example:

```
## Raster with more than 256 values
r <- raster::raster(matrix(1:10000, ncol = 100))
raster::writeRaster(r, 'C:/temp/10000.tif')

## Fast GDAL implementation, but limited to 256 values
currentHist <- capture.output(gdalUtilities::gdalinfo('C:/temp/10000.tif', hist = TRUE ) )
## R option to calulate the values, but very slow in big files
desiredAndVerySlowHist <- table(r[])
```

Comment: So far couldn't find a way to do that either... Why not read the values into R and calculate the histogram there? Memory limitation?

Comment: Yes, Michael. Extremely big files

Comment: If there is no other solution, you can always read the raster in chunks. First figure out the dimensions (this can be done without reading the entire file), then run a loop that goes over 1000 rows each time, for instance. The 'stars' package can be used to do that:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stars/vignettes/stars2.html#reading-chunks-change-resolution-select-bands

Comment: You might also want to check out `freqDT()` in the [**rasterDT**](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rasterDT/index.html) package. It processes large rasters in chunks and will likely get you at least a 6-fold speedup ([see here for example](https://github.com/JoshOBrien/rasterDT)) relative to `raster::freq()`.

Comment: Thanks, @Josh !!. I think that a super good option for me. `freqDT` function seems very powerful. It is possible to use that function for an external raster file without loading it into the RAM? Congratulations for the package. It's a promising tool.

Comment: @gonzalez.ivan90 Yes, the functions in **rasterDT** are all written to handle rasters that are too large to process in RAM. Let me know how `freqDT()` ends up working for you in the end.